# Made a reg edit to force Chrome to open in Desktop mode in Windows 8, now everything is broken

Tags: windows, windows-8, google-chrome, windows-registry, regedit

I made this reg file edit to open chrome in desktop mode in windows 8:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ChromeHTML\shell\open\command]
 "DelegateExecute"=-
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Chrome\.exe\shell\open\command]
 "DelegateExecute"=-
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Chrome\.exe\shell\opennewwindow\command]
 "DelegateExecute"=-
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Chrome\.exe\shell
un\command]
 "DelegateExecute"=-
```

I don't think this works with the newest version of Chrome. Now clicking on the chrome icon does nothing, and now the application isn't available to uninstall. I"m stuck. Can anyone tell me how I can un-do what I just did. I know someone will tell me to never mess with editing my registry without making a backup. Lesson learned =/

Comment: Delete/remove/undo/reverse the changes you made to the Registry.

Comment: Reinstall chrome?

Comment: @joeqwerty I don't know what changes I made. I mean I "see" the changes above, but I found them on the internet and I don't know how to "undo" them.

Comment: @tumchaaditya I tried to un-install chrome, but now it doesn't show up in the add/remove programs list in Windows =(

Comment: just run the installer again. It should take care of things. And always backup registry before messing with it

Comment: You can always delete those entries.  The reinstall of Chrome should replace them if they are required.  I am not sure the reason you did this, because by default, Chrome always launches in Desktop mode unless you launch it from the start screen and its your default browser.